# Cocoa - set image and alternateImage for NSView as NSStatusItem in status bar

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nsstatusitem

I wanted to drop files in status bar app icon, so I've found implementation code that allows use NSView as NSStatusItem.
I'm trying to set image directly to view, but nothing happens I still getting empty status bar item. The menu works fine, just can't set the icon image.

```c
NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
[imageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"static.png"]];
[self addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Mind if you share more code involving the NSStatusItem?

Comment: just followed this guide - http://undefinedvalue.com/2009/07/07/adding-custom-view-nsstatusitem

Comment: Check if the line of code is called by using a linebreak or `NSLog`

Comment: My code above is called with `- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame` method in my NSView subclass.

Comment: Any ideas why can't I set icon?